# Explosion of memory using std::map

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dictionary, memory, stl

I have a problem by using std::map in C++ for VS10.
When I run this simple code

```
std::map<int,int>myMap;
for(size_t i=0;i<1000000;i++){
     myMap[i]=i;
}
```

My memory explodes to 256Mo which seems very strange for me.
And if I use

```
std::vector<int>myVector(1000000);
```

I obtain 4Mo as predicted.

If anybody can explain this phenomena.
Thanks

Comment: Is this a joke? You know the difference between std::map and std::vector implementations, right?

Comment: node size is probably (parentptr, leftptr, rightptr, color, key, value), so ~8+8+8+1+padding+4+4+padding=40bytes each. Add in ~24 bytes each for allocation overhead in Windows leads to a total of ~64 bytes per node, x1000000 = 61Mb. Hm. I'd only expect to see ~4Mb over that for unused page allocations. Not sure where the other 200Mb are from.

Comment: Are you sure it's 256 Mb, not 25.6? I would expect a little under 24 Mb for a million-node map, i.e. 4 for the value, 4 for the node, and 8+8 for the left and right pointers.

Comment: How are you measuring the memory usage?

Answer (score 2):

`std::map` is likely implemented as a red-black tree which means the following fields, assuming x64:

1. Red or black (1 boolean, but effectively 4 bytes due to padding)
2. Parent (8 byte pointer)
3. Left child, Right child (two 8 byte pointers)
4. Root object (8 byte pointer)
5. Data Key (4 bytes for int)
6. Data Value (4 bytes for int)

This gets you up to 44 bytes per item or 44 Megabytes of memory. Also unlike in `std::vector` case each of these is independently an object which adds roughly 24 bytes of additional data. Which brings us to 68 Megabytes. That is still a quarter of what you are seeing but at least you can see why there is a huge difference in sizes.

Comment: I ran a test using Visual Studio 2015, and got about 45MB memory used from running the exact code the OP provided (went from ~4MB at baseline to 49MB while the object existed, then went back down to 4MB when the object was destructed). I suspect it is optimizing the object allocations, as that basically just puts it right above the raw memory use by the object itself, ignoring the "allocation overhead" you and another user identified.

Comment: @Xirema: I did my best to stress that I was listing "worst possible" numbers that I don't think are necessarily accurate, just showing how high numbers are possible.